# Sort a file like another file

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

I have 2  text files :

1st file :

```
1  C
1  D
1  B
1  A
```

2nd file :

```
B
C
D
A
```

I want to sort first file like this:

```
1 B
1 C
1 D
1 A
```

Can you help me with a script in bash (or command ).

Comment: Does every line start only by `1` character and space? Or it can be any number/string?

Comment: only 1 and space . It is a number (same to any line)

Comment: I can remove first column and space. Now i am tring to sort first file like the second ( line by line).

Comment: Are the values in the 2nd file unique or can they repeat?

Answer (score 0):

and what only to ignore the first file and do this?

```
echo -n > result-file.txt # empty result file if already created
while read line; do
  echo "1 $line" >> result-file.txt
done < file2.txt
```

It would make sense when your files' format is specific.

Comment: instead of `cat file | while ...`, it is better to say `while ... done < file`.

Comment: It's much more efficient to iterate within sed etc. like `sed 's/.*/1 &/' file2.txt`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the sort problem (i eliminated the first column ) and use this script

```
awk 'FNR == NR { lineno[$1] = NR; next}
 {print lineno[$1], $0;}' ids.txt   resultpartial.txt | sort -k 1,1n | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

Now I want to add ( first column like before)

1 .....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the "sort" field contains no duplicated values:

```
awk 'FNR==NR {line[$2] = $0; next} {print line[$1]}' file1 file2
```